# API Explorer: Including Envelope Custom Fields

Tags: docusignapi

Trying to send from a DS template that has a required envelope custom field.  From documentation I'd expect a Custom Field selection under envelopeId but not finding it.
Is this supported in the DS API explorer?  Thanks!

Error code: ENVELOPE_CUSTOM_FIELD_MISSING.
Message: A required envelope custom field is missing. The custom field 'Cost Center' requires a value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API call - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopecustomfields/create/

So, you may need 3 API calls:

1. Create envelope in "draft" status.
2. Add custom fields.
3. Send it.

There may be a way to do this with fewer API calls, but I don't know how.

Comment: Hi Inbar.  Thanks for getting back to me.  I think it can be done in a single call but would need to use Postman to verify.  I was just curious if the web based API Explorer from the Dev Center supported this since I wasn't finding it where I expected it would live.  More of a curiosity and I am not blocked.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure which API call you mean, API Explorer is supposed to support all of them